# .LastWriteTime.ToString returning spurious month

Tags: powershell, datetime-format

I have a file, "benevoles-2.sty," that just contains 5 lines of text. I query its `LastWriteTime`:

```
PS> (gi benevoles-2.sty).lastwritetime
28 September 2023 10:59:17
PS> (gi benevoles-2.sty).lastwritetime.tostring('yyyy-mm-dd-hh:mm:ss')
2023-59-28-10:59:17
```

September is showing as month 59 of 2023! This is happening now with dozens of files on my system, and only recently. Has something changed in the `ToString` method?

Comment: You have a typo because `mm` is for Minutes and `MM` is for Month :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike in native Unix-like environments, on **Windows** as well as in **.NET / PowerShell** *irrespective of the host platform*, **`mm` refers to the *minutes*** in a date/time format string, and **`MM` to the *month* number**, so you need the latter:

```bash
(gi benevoles-2.sty).lastwritetime.tostring('yyyy-MM-dd-hh:mm:ss')
```

- See [*Custom* date and time format strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) for explicitly specified, case-*sensitive* custom formats...
- and [*Standard* date and time format strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) for predefined, case-*insensitive*, single-character standard formats.
- To disambiguate a single-character *custom* specifier from a *standard* one, prepend `%`.
  E.g., `Get-Date -Format %M` (same as: `[datetime]::Now.ToString('%M')`) uses the *custom* specifier `M` (the non-padded month number, e.g., `11`), whereas `Get-Date -Format M` uses the *standard* `M` specifier (the month/day pattern, e.g. `November 20`)
- PowerShell's [`Get-Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date) cmdlet offers *Unix*-style format strings via its `-UFormat` parameter, on all platforms.

  - E.g, `Get-Date -UFormat %s` returns the current point in time as Unix epoch time (number of seconds since midnight, 1 Jan 1970).<sup>[1]</sup>

---

<sup>[1] **Caveat**: In the legacy *Windows PowerShell* edition, this unexpectedly returns *fractional* seconds and uses midnight *local* time as the reference point; both problems have been corrected in the modern, cross-platform [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) edition.</sup>